# Express middleware blocked by CORS policy (hitting authorization error for preflight OPTIONS request)

Tags: node.js, express, cors, authorization, preflight

When this block is not present, my API works perfectly.

When I add this block in, I get a CORS error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

What am I missing?

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (secret !== config.secret) {
      throw new Error('Not Authorized')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: That removed the CORS error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the error is not thrown if the request's method is OPTIONS:

```
if (req.method !== "OPTIONS" && secret !== config.secret) {
  throw ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request.